# Нужна ли запятая (см.)?

Tags: запятые

*А тот факт, что Вы этому ограниченному чудовищу рукоплещете, у меня не вызвал никакого удивления.*

Нужна ли тут запятая после "рукоплещете"? Если да, то почему? Мне почему-то кажется, что она тут лишняя; с другой стороны, тут вроде как виднеются две грамматические основы, да и часть со "что" выглядит как обособление.

Answer (score 1):

Нужна, закрывает придаточное.

Первая основа: *факт не вызвал удивления;*

вторая: *Вы рукоплещете.*

Главное: *А тот факт у меня не вызвал никакого удивления.*

Придаточное внутри главного: *что Вы этому ограниченному чудовищу рукоплещете.*